# newbie stuck: ASIHTTPRequest - no known class method for selector 'requestWithURL'

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest

I am referencing `ASIHTTPRequest` and got it to compile in `iOS5`.

However when I try to use it:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

I get the error

```
no known class method for selector 'requestWithURL'.
```

Also `setCacheStoragePolicy` and `startAsynchronous` throw errors.

Indeed I can't see that method in the `ASIHTTPRequest.m` file.  What am I missing?
This is the latest code download from `github`.

Thanks,
   John.

Answer (score 0):

Go to target and check ASIHTTPRequest.m is a part of compiler source or not.

Make a clean build and try to build one more time. I

f that don’t work,  try to update your code. I can see those method in github code.

Comment: Yes it looks like I didn't have the right codebase after all.  Now I've updated that but am getting undeclared identifier on kReachabilityChangedNotification.

Is there some framework I'm supposed to add to get that?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have CFNetwork.framework, SystemConfiguration.framework, MobileCoreServices.framework, CoreGraphics.framework and libz.dylib added into your project.

kReachabilityChangedNotification is declared in Reachability.h(which is located in a folder called "External" in the ASIHTTPRequest package), so make sure to add Reachability.h & Reachability.m from the "External" folder into your project